# Initial connection to static IP is slower

Tags: ip, static-ip, printer, domain-name-system

We have a simple printer running a jetdirect service on 9100 listening for incoming characters. It is sits behind a modem that serves a static IP to a router. I can telnet in and print arbitrary characters. Oddly, the first connection takes much longer then the next one. I setup a script to continually ping the address every three minutes. When I attempt to connect after setting this script up the connection is, more or less, instantaneous. This might make sense if there was some sort of dynamic address resolution but I don't understand why it is working this way with a static IP. The connection is ADSL2+ through SureWest.

I'm sure it's something I'm overlooking. Please enlighten me.

Comment: The initial description sounds a lot like a dns resolution timeout, then maybe caching of the failure makes it work. But I wouldn't expect a ping to trigger a lookup. In any case, does the printer have a dns server configured it can't connect too?

Comment: I was expecting something similar, but this is using the SureWest network. I'm thinking it might be the case that they assign static addresses differently with some sort of caching layer perhaps....

Answer (score 1):

Does the printer and/or JetDirect module sleep? If so it might take a few seconds to wake up.

Comment: Neither the printer nor the JetDirect module sleep. We have a couple hundred other of these printers deployed and this is the first time we are seeing this issue.